# Is there anyway to receive notification of iphone addressbook contacts modification?

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I am doing an app that writes contacts to iphone addressbook contacts. And the app needs to know when the contacts it wrote to the addressbook is modified by the user. Is there any way to register for some sort of notification from the addressbook? Really appreciate any help.